# How to put validation in mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-material

I have multiple rows with mat-select.I want to be able to put validation such a way that I should be able to choose minimum of 1 value each.If I don't select 1 value of each type from mat-select then i should not be able to proceed to next step.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">Type
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-select placeholder="Select Type" [(ngModel)]="type.text" (selectionChange)="changed($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typeColumn  let i = index" [value]="{type: type.text, index: i}" [disabled]="!type.allowed && type.allowed != undefined">
                  {{ type.text }} 
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
```

This html code allows me to display mat-select and displays list of dropwdown values.

```
  typeColumn = [
{text:'None'},
{text:'Time',allowed: true},
{text:'Segment'},
{text:'Key',allowed: true},
{text:'Input'},
{text:'Quantile' } ];
```

This is the list of drop down options that i get.

I need a validation that the user should select at least one value of each Time,Key,Segment,Input and Key before proceeding to next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to help as you are not posting the complete code e.g. a stackblitz. Especially as it looks like you are using a `mat-table` and probably want to persist the changes to the datasource.

I threw a quick stackblitz together [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-stdf8h?file=app/app.component.ts) that just displays 6 `mat-select` elements and checks upon `selectionChange()` whether or not all the types that are marked with the property `required` are selected. This is reflected in the variable `isValid` and based on this you could let the user advance to the next step or not.

This should give you a rough idea of how to proceed with the validation. For a more precise answer you would need to post more of your code and data, preferably a working stackblitz.

Comment: I can't add stackblitz because the mat-table data is populated from API. The stackblitz you posted is correct but I want the feature that there should be a next button and before clicking on Next button i should have selected atleast one Time,Key,Segment in dropdown. Without selecting I should not be able to proceed further

Comment: You can always mock the data / provide static data in your stackblitz. If all you mean by that is a button that is enabled/disabled then [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-qw9ncd?file=app/app.component.html) is an updated stackblitz.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. I have up voted your answer and also chosen it as the accepted answer.